# Laravel PDF exports a huge of data

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation, dompdf, mpdf

I have found a problems about exporting PDF document by laravel-pdf.

I have used this library - https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf

So I would like to export a huge of data to PDF (around ~10,000 rows).

The memory limit and max execution time were occurring when I tired to export them.

Many times, I tired to increase memory limit and max execution time on php.ini, but it didn't works. And I thought that its not a really correct solution (I have already increased memory limit up-to 2000mb. It worked for around ~5,000 rows and it take time more than 3 minutes).

Here is my simply code.

```
return PDF::loadView('report.member_report_pdf', ['data' => $huge_data], [], [
            'format' => 'A2-L',
        ])->stream('report'.pdf');
```

Here is my errors I got.

```
[04-Oct-2017 19:04:43 Asia/Bangkok] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 320 seconds exceeded in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tab_member/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Frame.php on line 325
[04-Oct-2017 19:15:15 Asia/Bangkok] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tab_member/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 24005
```

Comment: If you check the values of `phpinfo()` do you see your php.ini values? If not, your hosting provider may not let you override these values. I can not see any other reason for this failing other than PHP running out of memory. There is no getting around that unless you fork the project and try to minimize the memory footprint.

Comment: I have already increased memory limit up-to 2000mb. It worked for around ~5,000 rows and it take time more than 3 minutes.

Comment: I ment, when you increase these settings, to you see your values when you output `phpinfo()`? It could be that your hosting provider denies you access to overriding the php.ini values. 2GB memory should be more than enough.

Comment: Yes, I could see the values as same as my php.ini but its not enough.

Comment: What specifically is the error you are getting? Please post it here, along with the stacktrace.

Comment: I have already edited my post. You would see again.

Comment: I guess these were two error messages you got at different times. You just need to increase the values until it works. There is no other way of doing this, unless (like I already stated) you want to fork the component and reimplement it in a way that uses less memory.

Comment: Thanks. I will try again.

Comment: See https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/memory-problems.html troubleshooting page in the manual.